# Неправильно работает поиск в Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Установил elastic. Настроил индексацию. Но в запросах какая-то странность выходит. Никак не пойму почему поиск некорректно работает

Я делал запросы с помощью либы в ruby, и пенял на нее, однако когда отснифал запрос понял что тут проблема в самом elastic. Да это даже не проблема, скорее фича.

```
prod = Post.search "ра", fields: [:title] // На выходе n-элементов
prod = Post.search "разд", fields: [:title] // На выходе 0-элементов
prod = Post.search "раздел", fields: [:title] // На выходе n-элементов
```

Скорее всего где то надо найти настройку, которая позволит улучшить поиск.

Comment: Изолируйте проблему до [не]нахождения одной записи и приложите эту запись.

Comment: @D-side надо найти настройку которая увеличит индекс

Comment: @D-side начал конкурс

Comment: Я по-прежнему не вижу запрошенной информации, так что... ну, может, кто ещё найдётся.

Comment: @D-side я думал это на стороне рельс проблема. Это в самом elastic

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Скорее всего, это поведение анализатора. ES использует немного более сложную схему поиска, нежели привычное точное совпадение:

- При загрузке документа все текстовые поля пропускаются через анализатор, состоящий из токенайзера и фильтров
- Токенайзер бьет ввод на отдельные токены (как правило, это слова)
- Фильтры изменяют, добавляют и удаляют токены
- Токены записываются в конечный индекс
- При поиске запрос снова пропускается через анализатор, бьется на токены, и ES ищет совпадения между токенами запроса и токенами документа

Я подозреваю, что проблема именно в этом - в ES существуют токены "ра" и "раздел", но не существует токена "разд".

Скорее всего, дело именно в том, на какие токены разбивается запрос при поиске текущим анализатором. Чтобы проверить это, необходимо просмотреть токены совпадающих документов и токены запроса:

```
curl -XGET <es host>:9200/<index name>/_analyze -d '{
    "text": "разд"
}'

curl -XGET <es host>:9200/<index name>/_analyze -d '{
    "text": "раздел"
}'

curl -XGET <es host>:9200/<index name>/_analyze -d '{
    "text": "<текст документа>"
}'
```

<sub>* В случае, если при поиске используется анализатор, отличный от анализатора индекса по умолчанию - скорее всего, вопрос это не подразумевает - его можно указать в поле `"analyzer"`</sub>


<sub>* Токены документов можно получить [напрямую из elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13182001/2908793), но это немного сложнее</sub>

Если вы использовали все настройки по умолчанию, то у вас стоит стандартный анализатор, который (во всяком случае, у меня) даст следующие результаты:

- Ра
- Разд
- Раздел

<sub>(причем я смог добиться поиска по последним двум запросам, но даже при ненормально больших fuzziness ES отказася находить мне что-либо по "ра", что подталкивает к тому, что либо у вас все-таки нестандартный анализатор, либо я полностью забыл эластик)</sub>

После этого вы можете посмотреть, как именно совпадает или не совпадает документ, с помощью explain API:

```
curl -XGET <es host>:9200/<index name>/<type name>/<document id>/_explain -d '{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "query": "ра"
        }
    }
}'
```

<sub>* непосредственно запрос может отличаться и зависит от вашей библиотеки</sub>

Таким образом вы сможете найти причину этого поведения самостоятельно - со стороны коммьюнити это почти невозможно, пока вы не привели mapping соответствующего индекса в ES, документы, которые совпадает по двум из трех запросов, непосредственно сам запрос, который передает библиотека и версию ES. Однако, насколько я понимаю, конкретно за этим вопросом стоит необходимость сделать автокомплит - в этом случае вам нужен не поиск внутри ES, а [suggester completion](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html) - это немного другой функционал ES, который создан именно для реализации автокомплита.

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, как ввести параметр на минимальное количество совпадений в одном слове разбитых токенайзером ngram. Например слово "приора" разбитора на "при", "прио", приор" вот как заставить эластик искать как минимум по трем совпадениям в одном слове, а не по одному

Comment: @Pavel разве что сделать bool/should query с необходимым минимальным количеством совпадений и term query с указанным примером внутри каждой ветки